# VS Code - How to continue on the next line?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

everytime when I press enter to continue in the next line, VS Code jumps backs on the last line. I tried to put `<br>` at the end of the last line, but as you can see on the screenshot, that also doesn't help. I guess I have to change something within the settings of VS Code, but I didn't find anything.

[Here and image](https://github.com/ChristophGrothe/christophgrothe.github.io/blob/main/vsc%20problem.jpg?raw=true)

[Here the whole code](https://github.com/ChristophGrothe/christophgrothe.github.io/blob/main/index.html)

Anybody an idea what I can do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not an error. I didn't see the code that time as it was not opening sorry.
Just create a new p tag as

And between it put br tag
This is not an error. you are using it wrongly.

```
    <p>Hi und Willkommen auf SAWÖ.at!</p>
    <br>
    <p> Da du hier gelandet bist, hast du vermutlich dasselbe Problem, das wir einmal hatten: Du willst selbstständig als Webesigner und/ 
oder Developer arbeiten, weißt jedoch nicht, wie du im bürokratischen 
Österreichden formellen Teil hinbekommst. Und du bist wahrscheinlich auch verwirrt, weil es da so viele verschiedene Fachbegriffe gibt wie zB Freiberufler, freie Berufe, Freelancer, Gewerbe usw... Keine Angst, jetzt ist Schluss mit dem Chaos! Wir erklärendir Step bei Step die wichtigsten Dinge, versprochen!</p>
```

Comment: Reinstalling didn't help. I found out that it always jumps back when the file is saved. So I deleted the autosave from settings.json. Now it only jumps back when I save on my own, what I also don't want ^^

Comment: Do One thing install an extension called as beautify it will do it's job

Comment: listen what is the problem you have with then just let it to be read solution

Comment: Oh my god, now I also see my mistake...I was using Devtools now for such a long time as my code editor that I apparently forgot how VS Code works ^^ Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry I'm completely new here and wanted to like you in some way but didn't know...now I found out ;)